# How do I add two pivot tables to the same Excel sheet through a SAS program using two SAS datasets as the pivot data sources?

Tags: vba, excel, sas

I have two SAS tables and I want to create pivot tables in Excel from them. Both must be in the same sheet, say `Sheet1`.

In the same sheet, I need to create a table that contains cells with formulae based on the first two pivots, e.g. `C3-C10`, where `C3` is a data point of the first pivot and `C10` from the second pivot.

An additional challenge would be to figure out a way to format and change colours of specific rows as required in the sheet.

Comment: What are you using? SAS AMO? SAS EG, Base, or Studio and version. Also as a minimum please provide a screen shot of desired output and what you've tried. For example is it the table structure you need or a native Excel pivot table. If it's a native Excel Pivot that's much more difficult.

Comment: @Reeza I'm using SAS EG 7.1 and yes, I need a native Excel Pivot. I found an article that helps me create a native pivot in [link] (http://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2015/03/27/using-sas-to-add-pivottables-to-your-excel-workbook/) . But I need to create two pivots both on the same page and then use them to create another table also on the same page.

Comment: Did you read the comments regarding issue with EG and this method? Also you're using SAS 9.4tS1M3? Can you run X commands on your installation?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for people that do not have any SAS Office Analytics, or the Office plugin, etc.  If you have some of the above tools (which I do not), there is probably a much better approach.

If you find yourself in this situation I suggest that you do the following:

1. Use SAS to create a CSV file that contains data that will drive the pivots.
2. Create an excel file that links to data in a CSV file.
3. Build the two pivots by hand, with the formatting you desire.
4. Whenever you need to refresh the data, just rerun the SAS job, and then 'refresh' the data in Excel (manually).

This also means you can update the data if people already have the excel file open, so it's suitable for files located on a network etc.  Pretty clunky but it will do when no better options are available.